# How to perform editing and filtering option with react hooks in React Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I wanted to know how to perform the filtering and editing option in react-data-grid library where the state (useState) holds the row data. It's easy to perform the editing option but I found filtering quite difficult. I was able to change the code where it is able to do filtering and editing option as well. Here the problem is where when I filter a row and when I get a single result and then I try to edit that row the edited row is not reflecting to the actual row. It is getting reflected to the 0th row. Can anyone please help me on this.